# declaring/reusing/composing match logic

Tags: xslt-3.0

consider this xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs kookerella"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:function name="kookerella:isId123" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="foo" as="element(Foo)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$foo/@id eq '123'"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:function name="kookerella:hasHair" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="foo" as="element(Foo)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="not(empty($foo/hair))"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="Wibble" select="Foo"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="Bar" select="Foo"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="Bar" match="Foo[kookerella:isId123(.)]">
        <Bar/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="Wibble" match="Foo[kookerella:isId123(.) and kookerella:hasHair(.)]">
        <Wibble/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The intention here is to capture 'match' logic in functions that then allows me to reuse/compose different conditions in different templates.

The above example works, but is there a different mechanism to do this (I have a feeling someone mentioned it once in another answer I cant find).

Comment: you can use modes....but I suppose you have to explain something more about your usecase.

Comment: its not about the modes its about the predicates inside the matches

Comment: What kind of different "mechanism" do you have in mind? A predicate expression is kind of a boolean function on the context item so your approach seems fine.

Comment: i thought i'd seen Michael Kay once mentioning somehow declaring the match pattern seperately from the template itself. If the above technique is sensible, i'll continue doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course, to a certain extent, use static parameters https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-params and shadow attributes https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes, to store parts of your predicates in parameters and reuse them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:kookerella="kookerella.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs kookerella"
    version="3.0">
  
    <xsl:param name="id-check" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'@id = ''123'''"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="hair-check" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'not(empty(hair))'"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="Wibble" select="Foo"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="Bar" select="Foo"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="Bar" _match="Foo[{$id-check}]">
        <Bar/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="Wibble" _match="Foo[{$id-check} and {$hair-check}]">
        <Wibble/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I would consider your shown approach the cleaner one.

Comment: ah ok, maybe that was it, so I'll stick with my function approach, thanks though.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, I only mentioned it as an option that is technically possible; as for Michael Kay, I had hoped he would see your question and give his opinion but perhaps he has not seen it; I kind of doubt he would use static params/shadow attributes for shortening/reusing match patterns that way.

Comment: I wonder whether you just saw an example where some variables or parameters were declared e.g. `<xsl:param name="foo1-sequence" select="//foo[some-predicate-expression]"/> and `<xsl:param name="foo2-sequence" select="//foo[some-other-predicate]"/>` and then used e.g. `<xsl:template match="$foo1-sequence">`, `<xsl:template match="$foo2-sequence">`, and e.g. `<xsl:template match="$foo1-sequence intersect $foo2-sequence">`.

Comment: i think thats it...